# How to add an object whose key is in a variable to an index in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects and want to add a new object to it in a for loop. They key of the object is dynamic and inside a variable. How can I do this. My array:

```
var myKey = "someStringThatIsDynamic";   
var myArray[i].myKey = "myValue";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `bracket` notation.

```
var myKey = "someStringThatIsDynamic";   
var myArray[i][myKey] = "myValue";
```

That allows you to assign the properties `dynamically`. With the other words, at `runtime`.

**Note** : Using square bracket notation allows the use of characters that can't be used with dot notation:

```
var foo = myForm.key[]; // incorrect syntax
var foo = myForm["key[]"]; // correct syntax
```